# Accessing a private file from another gitlab repository

Tags: python, gitlab, request, gitlab-ci

I'm building a CI pipeline where I want to read a specific file from a different private repository. I'm the owner of both repositories, but the plan is to open one to my coworkers while mantaining the second one as a baseline and private, with access only for me. Here the expected results from different test are stored and the pipeline should compare the results achieved to the baselines when ran.

However, I'm running continuosly to a request error where the files are not accessible (response status code 403)

I tried retrieving the files via request with python:

```
# GitLab private token
PRIVATE_TOKEN = 'my-private-token'
# The URL of the raw file in the private repository
FILE_URL = 'https://gitlab.com/{username}/{repo-name}/-/raw/main/{file1}'

# Set up the headers for authentication
headers = {'Authorization': f'token {PRIVATE_TOKEN}'}
```

and also

```
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {PRIVATE_TOKEN}'}
```

to finally call requests

```
response = requests.get(FILE_URL, headers=headers)
```

But always receiving response status code 403

Answer (score 0):

Your private token only allows you to access API URLs, not frontend UI URLs.

For example, to get file contents, you would need to use the [Repository Files API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html).

```py
from base64 import b64decode

headers = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': PRIVATE_TOKEN}
branch = 'main'
project_id = 278964
params = {'ref': branch}
api_url = f'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{project_id}/repository/files/{file_name}'
resp = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, params=params)
resp.raise_for_status()
encoded_contents = resp.json()['content']
decoded_contents_bytes = b64decode(encoded_contents)

print(decoded_contents_bytes)
```

---

Since you're using Python, a convenient way to interact with the API is using the [`python-gitlab` package](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gl_objects/projects.html#project-files).

```py
import gitlab  # pip install python-gitlab
TOKEN = 'your private token'
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.com', private_token=TOKEN)

project_id = 'gitlab-org/gitlab'  # or use numerical ID

project = gl.projects.get(project_id)
raw_content = project.files.raw(
    file_path='.gitlab-ci.yml', 
    ref=project.default_branch
)

print(raw_content)
```